# Dojo dgrid pagination issue using editor

Tags: dojo, pagination, editor

I am facing problem while using dgrid pagination with editor column.

I had one column with check box implemented using editor.

when ever I am selected 2 rows in the first page and then after I am selecting the few more rows in the second page.When ever I come back by clicking on the back arrow in pagination,the data is erasing and it is throwing one issue like "row.data is undefined"

Thanks in advance for ur valuable suggestions.